# System of Equation Problem? 52x + 16y = 100

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have forgotten how to solve this type of problem.

> $$52x + 16y = 100$$

Is this the method?

Substitute $0$ for $x$

$$0+ 16y = 100\\y= 100/16 \\y= 6.25$$

Substitute $0$ for $y$

$$52x+0 = 100\\x=100/52\\x= 1.92$$

This can't be right.

Comment: with your method, 52x + 16y = 200.
Moreover, what are $x$ and $y$? Real? Integers?

Comment: You can convert the equation in form of $x$ or $y$.

Comment: @Exodd I think if anything is not mentioned than we have to consider $x$ and $y$ as real.

Comment: @hey I know, but the formulation of the problem makes me think it wants the integer solutions..

Comment: @Exodd Oh yes i see he has written $x$ can not be 1.92.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have one equation, but two variables, it's impossible to find the exact values of $x$ and $y$ without more information.

You *can* write $x$ in terms of $y$:

$$52x+16y=100$$

$$52x=100-16y$$

$$x=\frac{25-4y}{13}$$

... or $y$ in terms of $x$:

$$52x+16y=100$$

$$16y = 100 - 52x$$

$$y = \frac{25-13x}{4}$$

You can also [graph the equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+52x%2B16y%3D100) in the [$xy$-plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system).

---

What you worked out were two *pairs* of solutions $(x,y)$:

$$(x,y) = (0,6.25)$$

$$(x,y) \approx (1.92,0)$$

Both of these satisfy your original equation, but they aren't the only ones.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=t$ be a parameter variable. Then $\displaystyle y = \frac{100-52x}{16} = \frac{25-13t}{4}$. So the solution set is
$$
\bigg\{ \Big(t,\frac{25-13t}{4}\Big):t\in\mathbb{R}\bigg\}
$$